# Passing MobX @observable of array to React Component props of PropTypes.array

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

So I'm using a vanilla React UI component library and MobX as state management in my app. When I have an observable of array as data and I want to pass it down from my component (which is a `mobx-react` `observer`) to the UI library's component (which the prop is the type of `PropTypes.array`), the component rejects it saying my observable array is an object, not an array.

```js
// my store
class Store {
  @observable data = [...];
}


// my component
@inject('store')
@observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const {store} = this.props;
    return <LibComponent data={store.data} />
  }
}

// library's component
class LibComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array,
    ....
  }
}
```

I've read about using `toJS` from mobx in this similar [question](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/658), but is there any other way to work around this? As I'm not the owner of the UI library I can't add PropTypes validations which come in `mobx-react` package mentioned in that question as answer. Will the UI library react to change with `toJS` as input of its prop?

Comment: I think no other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mobx-react ships with it's own `propTypes`, which you can use: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#proptypes

Comment: Thx @mweststrate, I do know that `mobx-react` have its own propTypes but it's for the component library. Meanwhile I'm trying to use such library which doesn't use `mobx-react` propTypes to validate its prop, but a standar `prop-types` of array type. Is there any workaraound?

Comment: Library components should probably not be receiving observables in the first place (unless they are observers themselves). Just convert to plain data in the closest surround observer component

Answer (score 1):

It is because a mobx array is actually an object.

Documents state that whenever a situation like yours occurs data should be passed as;

```
data.slice()
```

In order to turn it into a normal array. Since the library in question most likely lacks the observer decorators as well, I think even if you were to pass the observable down with its reactive qualities, it wouldn't work. Therefore you should either handle this as a nonreactive data, or fork the library to accommodate this need.